# Change a delivery boy needs to carry

Tags: probability, machine-learning, data-analysis

> There are total 991 deliveries, to be done by N delivery boys.  Each
>   delivery boy can handle upto 40 deliveries. So the deliveries can be
>   distributed in chunks of 40, in the same order of Delivery No, to each
>   delivery boy.
>
> Probability distribution: Each customer has a following likelihood of
>   least denomination of notes he is paying with.
>
> - 1000 - 2%
> - 500 - 40%
> - 100 - 30%
> - 50 - 20%
> - 20 - 5%
> - 10 - 3%
>
> **Questions:**
>
> - What the amount of change, and in what denomination, should each    delivery boy carry?
> - What is the cost function of the model? What is being optimised,    (maximized or minimized)?

***What are the concepts required to solve this problem? I am beginner in data analytics or decision science, so please guide me.***

*Order number and order amount are given as excel sheet for all 991 orders. If required, can be provided.*

Comment: What should the customers pay? If they should all pay 1000, then it doesn't matter what their lowest denomination is, they can all pay exactly and the delivery boys don't need change. And do the customers have all higher denominations available? For instance, if a customer should pay 50, and has 20 available, do they also have 50 available, or does that require 10 in change?

Comment: @Arthur, the customers have to pay the money of the order amount that they have ordered. Example: Order 1 is of 329.8(rupees/dollars etc), Order 2 is of 1619 and so on. 

No information given on availability of higher denomination notes.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer.  No information on the cost of the orders, nor the rest of the money the customers have, means we can't tell how much change needs to be given out.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a combination of very precise data (in the Excel sheet) and very vague questions.

Here is one possible approach.

If a customer has only $1000$ denomination notes then the delivery boy will *on average* have to give the customer $500$ in change (in some cases it will be more than this, in other cases less). Out of $40$ deliveries the delivery boy expects $40 \times 2 \% = 0.8$ such customers on average. So he should carry $0.8 \times 500 = 400$ in change for these customers.

Go through the other groups of customers in the same way and add up the total amount of change that is required for each group of customers, and you get a total of $5226$ in change for each 24 delivery boys and for the 25th delivery boy delivering 31 deliveries, it will be 4050.

The "what denomination" part of the question is impossible to answer without more information. And the "cost function" is something that should be given in the question. Are we trying to minimize the amount of change carried by each delivery boy? Or the number of notes carried by each delivery boy? Or the probability that a delivery boy cannot give a customer change ? Or the average number of customers who cannot be given change? The question should provide this information.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and making it clear to me what is possible to find out and what is not. I am not able to get any details about missing info. I am too trying some other methods to solve. If I end up in any realistic/logical solution, will update.